# Ansible playbook to post message into kafka topic

Tags: ansible, kafka

```
Playbook 1:
---
- name: Message into topic
  hosts: web1
  become: yes
  tasks:
    - name: post message
      expect:
        shell: "/usr/local/kafka/bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic testTopic"
        responses:
          Question:
            - "Hi there"
```

Playbook 2:

```
- name: Message into topic
  hosts: web1
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - name: post message
      shell:
        command: /usr/local/kafka/bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic testTopic
        responses:                    
          (?i)Message: "Hello From Playbook"
```

---

Tried with the above two playbooks and ended up with some errors. Unable to find a proper solution for this. [enter image description here][1]

```
root@ip-172-31-83-195:/usr/local/kafka# bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic testTopic
```

> hello there
> Hi there

### This was the command I am trying to run in the playbook. If you have any examples that can take to other prompt like above command(ctrl+c is to come out of the prompt). Please let me know how we can use them in the playbook.
Thanks in advance!

Errors:

```
Error: For Playbook 1

root@ip-172-31-87-7:~# ansible-playbook Playbook_to_post_message_into_the_topic.yaml

PLAY [Message into topic] ***********************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [post message] *****************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [172.31.83.195]: FAILED! => {"ansible_facts": {"discovered_interpreter_python": "/usr/bin/python3"}, "changed": true, "cmd": "/bin/bash -c \"/usr/local/kafka/bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list 54.87.252.89:9092 --topic testTopic\"", "delta": "0:00:30.407263", "end": "2022-02-16 08:32:24.990783", "msg": "non-zero return code", "rc": 129, "start": "2022-02-16 08:31:54.583520", "stdout": ">[2022-02-16 08:32:07,214] WARN [Producer clientId=console-producer] Bootstrap broker 54.87.252.89:9092 (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)\r\n[2022-02-16 08:32:24,532] WARN [Producer clientId=console-producer] Bootstrap broker 54.87.252.89:9092 (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)", "stdout_lines": [">[2022-02-16 08:32:07,214] WARN [Producer clientId=console-producer] Bootstrap broker 54.87.252.89:9092 (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)", "[2022-02-16 08:32:24,532] WARN [Producer clientId=console-producer] Bootstrap broker 54.87.252.89:9092 (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)"]}

PLAY RECAP **************************************************************************************************************************************************
172.31.83.195              : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Error: for Playbook 2

```
PLAY [Message into topic] ***********************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [post message] *****************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [172.31.83.195]: FAILED! => {"ansible_facts": {"discovered_interpreter_python": "/usr/bin/python3"}, "changed": false, "msg": "Unsupported parameters for (command) module: command, responses Supported parameters include: _raw_params, _uses_shell, argv, chdir, creates, executable, removes, stdin, stdin_add_newline, strip_empty_ends, warn"}

PLAY RECAP **************************************************************************************************************************************************
172.31.83.195              : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: Where is the error itself ?

Comment: Thanks for the response @ALex_hha , added the errors below. As the command will take to other prompt. So not sure how it is gona suppose to be written in playbook.